# Detaching disk from stopped instance

Tags: google-api, google-compute-engine, google-api-python-client

I am trying to detach a disk from a stopped instance which is currently holding the disk. here's how I am doing it currently.

```
def detach_disk_from_instance(disk_name, zone=GCLOUD_ZONE):
    disk_info = get_disk_info(disk_name=disk_name, zone=zone)
    if disk_info.get('users'):
        instance_name = disk_info['users'][0].rsplit('/').pop()
        logger.info("detatching disk : {} from instance : {}".format(disk_name, instance_name))
        request = compute.instances().detachDisk(
            project=GCLOUD_PROJECT_NAME, zone=zone, instance=instance_name, deviceName=disk_name)
        return make_http_request(request, {})

def wait_for_operation(operation, zone=GCLOUD_ZONE, worker=1):
    logger.info('Waiting for operation {} to finish...'.format(operation))
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(worker) as executor:
        future = executor.submit(_check_operation_status, operation=operation, zone=zone)
        wait([future])
        return future.result()

req = detach_disk_from_instance(disk_name='test-disk')
wait_for_operation(operation=req['name'])
```

above code works if instance which is holding the disk is currently running.
but it doesn't work if instance is stopped. I get the following error when I try to detach disk from a stopped instance.

> {'errors': [{'message': "No attached disk found with device name
>   'test-disk'", 'code': 'INVALID_USAGE'}]}

and I assure you that disk is still attached to the instance and gcp dashboard also shows that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** - You're passing the `name` of the disk resource instead of the `device name` by which the disk is attached to the instance.

In the [`instances.attachDisk`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/attachDisk) request to attach a disk to a VM instance you can specify the device name in the [`deviceName`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/attachDisk#request-body) field of the request.

> **deviceName**
>
> string
>
> Specifies a unique device name of your choice that
>   is reflected into the /dev/disk/by-id/google-* tree of a Linux
>   operating system running within the instance. This name can be used to
>   reference the device for mounting, resizing, and so on, from within
>   the instance.
>
> If not specified, the server chooses a default device name to apply to
>   this disk, in the form **persistent-disks-x, where x is a number
>   assigned by Google Compute Engine**. This field is only applicable for
>   persistent disks.

You will need to use this name as the `deviceName` query parameter for the [`instances.detachDisk`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/detachDisk) request.

> Required query parameters
>
> **deviceName**
>
> string
>
> Disk device name to detach.

As mentioned in the doc, if you did not specify a device name while attaching the disk GCE generates a device name in the form `persistent-disks-x` and you will have to specify this name.